# hasfocus event in knockout not working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, oracle-commerce-cloud

I am using knockout `hasfocus` event for phone number validation,while focus out from input field validation error should get poped-up but it only happens when i click it second time if i try it for first time nothing happens 
I have tried to debug it with adding a break-point into the function so i figure that the error msg was getting showed up but something is happening and the error msg is getting removed for the first click
Could someone help please ?

```js
widget.isShippingPhoneFocus.subscribe(function (newValue) {
          if (!newValue) {
            var phoneValid = widget.validatePhone();
            if (!phoneValid) {
              widget.isPhoneValid(false);
              $('#CC-checkoutAddressBook-sphone-error').text(widget.phoneErrorMsg());
              $('#CC-checkoutAddressBook-sphone-error').show();
            } else {
              $('#CC-checkoutAddressBook-sphone-error').hide();
              widget.isPhoneValid(true);
            }
          }
        });
```

```html
<input type="tel" class="form-control" name="sPhone" id="CC-checkoutAddressBook-sphone" data-bind="validatableValue: phoneNumber, widgetLocaleText:{value:'phoneNumberText',attr:'placeholder'}, valueUpdate:'keyup', hasFocus: $parent.isShippingPhoneFocus">
```

Comment: where are you setting/changing value for widget.isShippingPhoneFocus ?

Answer (score 0):

at the begining while you are applying the bindings for the widget try to give false value for the isShippingPhoneFocus. It might solve the issue.